Understanding the Relationship between the Formula of an Equation and its Impact of an Algorithm
In the context of Decision Tree algorithms (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_learning), two approaches are generally used to build the tree (Gini Impurity and Entropy/Information Gain).
For example (and for simplicity sake), consider a dataset with categorical predictors $x_1, x_2, ... x_n$ and binary response variable $y$ (e.g. yes/no).
Below I tried to write what I understand from these approaches.

Gini Impurity:

The Gini Impurity $G(p)$ for a node, where $p$ is the proportion of items in the node that belong to the positive class, is given by:
$$G(p) = 2p(1-p)$$
For a given split of a predictor variable into two groups (left and right nodes), with proportions $p_L$ and $p_R$ of items and Gini impurities $G_L$ and $G_R$ , the average Gini impurity of the split is:
$$G_{avg} = p_L G_L + p_R G_R$$
For the data points within the current level on all remaining predictors, the best split is chosen as the one that minimizes the average Gini impurity. This is done over all remaining predictor variables and all possible binary splits s of each predictor. Once a predictor has been selected for splitting, it is not considered again at the current level. This process is repeated until no more predictors are left to split on at the current level in the tree.
I tried to write this formula like like this:
$$ (i^*, s^*) = \arg\min_{i \in \text{{remaining predictors}}, s \in \text{{all possible binary splits on }} i} \left[ p_{L,i,s} G_{L,i,s} + p_{R,i,s} G_{R,i,s} \right] $$

Entropy/Information Gain:

The entropy $E(p)$ for a node, where $p$ is the proportion of items in the node that belong to the positive class, is given by:
$$E(p) = -p\log_2(p) - (1-p)\log_2(1-p)$$
Information gain is the reduction in entropy achieved by partitioning the original dataset. For a given split of a predictor variable into two groups (left and right nodes), with proportions $p_L$ and $p_R$ of items and entropies $E_L$ and $E_R$ , the information gain $IG$ of the split is:
$$IG = E_{parent} - p_L E_L - p_R E_R$$
where $E_{parent}$ is the entropy of the parent node before the split.
For the data points within the current level on all remaining predictors, the best split is chosen as the one that maximizes the information gain. This is done over all remaining predictor variables and all possible binary splits $s$ of each predictor. Once a predictor has been selected for splitting, it is not considered again at the current level. This process is repeated until no more predictors are left to split on at the current level in the tree.
I tried to write a similar formula to represent this concept:
$$ (i^*, s^*) = \arg\max_{i \in \text{{remaining predictors}}, s \in \text{{all possible binary splits on }} i} \left[ E_{parent} - p_{L,i,s} E_{L,i,s} - p_{R,i,s} E_{R,i,s} \right] $$
where $E_{parent}$ is the entropy of the parent node, $p_{L,i,s}$ and $p_{R,i,s}$ are the proportions of items in the left and right nodes after splitting predictor $i$ at split point $s$, and $E_{L,i,s}$ and $E_{R,i,s}$ are the entropies of these nodes.
This leads me to my question:

Informally, I can see that Decision Trees that are built using the Gini Impurity approach try to reduce the level of impurity as you go further down the tree. As you go further and further down the tree, the Gini Impurity tries to make sure the nodes within the tree are more and more homogeneous.

I can also see that Decision Trees that are built using Entropy/Information Gain approach try to increase the amount of information gain as you go further and further down the tree. As you descend the tree, splits are made in such a way, such that rarer events (i.e. a rare event has higher entropy) are isolated.


Thus, based on this analysis: From a mathematical perspective, based on the equations used for the splitting rules, how can I understand the impact that using either of these approaches on the overall structure of the tree?
For example, based on the mathematical equations used for the splitting rules, is one approach more likely to create deeper trees than the other? Is one approach more likely to have less populated nodes compared to the other?
